# Objective C: SQLite where-statement wont work when running another method first

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite, ios7

So basically I have an app that will provide tasks based on selected project. Both projects and tasks are stored in a SQLite database.

To get the current project id I compare the selected project (_selectedProject) to my database, to get the ID. This is done in my getSelectedProjectId method. However, when running this method in the getTasks method, the Where-statement wont work at all. If I don't run the getSelectedProjectId method first, it works just fine. Am I forgetting to release something? Or is it something else? Any ideas?

I'm pretty new to both SQLite and Objective C, so this may not be a complex issue. I have made sure the getSelectedProjectId method returns the correct project ID. I have also made sure the query that is run in the getTasks method is correct, and when running it through my terminal it returns a number of rows. In the app it returns nothing, provided I'm running the getSelectedProjectId somewhere in that method first.

This is the method that fetches the tasks:

```
- (void)getTasks
{
    [self openDB];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    int projectId = [self getSelectedProjectId];
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE project_id=%i", projectId];
    const char *query_statement = [query UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, query_statement, -1, &statement, NULL);

    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        // I add the task title to my array of tasks here.
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
}
```

And this is the method that gets the correct project id from the database:

```
- (int)getSelectedProjectId
{
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    NSString        *query              = [[NSString alloc]
                                       initWithFormat:@"SELECT id FROM projects WHERE title=\"%@\" LIMIT 0,1",
                                       _selectedProject];
    int             rowId               = 0;
    const char      *query_statement    = [query UTF8String];

    [self openDB];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, query_statement, -1, &statement, NULL);

    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        rowId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(_contactDB);

    return rowId;
}
```

Comment: When you call getSelectedProjectId you close the DB.  (Why not just open the DB and leave it open?)

Comment: Damn good call. That turned out to be the problem. Thanks!

PS. I read somewhere that the database connection should be closed everytime you're done using it. I assume for security purposes?

Comment: BTW:  Don't prefix methods with `get`.  Also, writing SQLite is generally a waste of time.  Use FMDB or, better yet if you are iOS/OS X only, use Core Data so you take advantage of all of the optimizations and features available to it.

Comment: I've been using SQLite in commercial iPhone apps for 4 years now.  We always leave the DB open.

Comment: @Mattias Six of one, half dozen the other.  Leaving it open all the time is generally OK, *but* you'll likely really want to close it when your app is backgrounded as the system/user may kill off the app.  As long as you don't have any pending transactions, it should generally be OK, but... better safe than sorry.  Also;  if you are going to use the SQLite APIs directly, you *must consider how to handle every error code returned by those APIs in the most correct fashion.*  Can't tell you the number of data loss / crashes boil down to "didn't handle that error code".

Comment: @bbum has a good point -- you should always check SQLite return codes!  If you did (and then logged sqlite3_errmsg if there was an error) you wouldn't be needing to post this question in the first place.  Checking return codes is mandatory for quality code.

Comment: I'll definitely improve my error handling. Thanks! One question though: Why not prefix my methods with "get"? I noticed prefixing with "init" causes errors, but my "get"-methods seem to be working. Is it just best practice?

Comment: The "get" issue is more of just a convention.  You do need to understand the specific implications of starting a method name with "alloc", "init", "new", "copy", and "set", though, as those actually affect with the compiler generates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occured because I closed the DB connection in my getSelectedProjectId-method. I'm now leaving my DB open instead, works like a charm.